# Python REST API not working properly in Docker container

Tags: python, rest, api, docker, scikit-learn

I created a simple ML API using python with flask. It gets data from sample.csv and trains a logistic regression model based on that. I also have a '/predict' endpoint where I can input parameters in for the model to predict.

Example
    `localhost:80/predict?weight1=1.2&weight2=0.00123&&weight3=0.45` will output `{ "predicted": 1}`

**main.py:**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from flask import Flask, request
import numpy as np

# Create Flask object to run
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Predicting status from other features"


@app.route('/predict')
def predict():
    # Get values from the server
    weight1 = request.args['weight1']
    weight2 = request.args['weight2']
    weight3 = request.args['weight3']

    testData = np.array([weight1, weight2, weight3]).reshape(1, -1)

    class_predicted = logisticRegr.predict(testData.astype(float))

    output = "{ \"predicted\": " + "\"" + class_predicted[0] + "\"" +  "}"

    return output


# Train and load the model based on the MetroPCS_Sample
def load_model():
    global logisticRegr
    label_y = []
    label_x = []

    with open('sample.csv') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines[1:]:
            # Adding labels to label_y
            label_y.append(int(line[0]))
            line = line.strip().split(",")
            x_data = []
            for e in line[1:]:
            # Adding other features to label_x
                x_data.append(float(e))
            label_x.append(x_data)


    train_x = label_x[:700]
    train_y = label_y[:700]

    test_x = label_x[700:1000]
    test_y = label_y[700:1000]

    logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()


    logisticRegr.fit(train_x, train_y)

    predictions = logisticRegr.predict(test_x)

    score = logisticRegr.score(test_x, test_y)
    # print score

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting Server...")

    # Call function that loads Model
    load_model()

    # Run Server
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", debug=True, port=80)
```

Everything works well when I run this script without a container.

However, when I placed it in a container and run it, I get the following error:

`NameError: global name 'logisticRegr' is not not defined`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python2.7

# copy over our requirements.txt file
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/

# upgrade pip and install required python packages
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app

ENV MESSAGE "hello"
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
numpy
sklearn
scipy
```

Do you know what can cause the NameError when the script is inside a container?

Answer (score 1):

in your `def load_model()`. you have `global logisticRegr`.
just using `global` keyword doesn't make your variable global.

global is used when you want to access and change global variable inside your function. since your `logisticRegr` is not global,

when you are trying to access it in `def predict()`,

`class_predicted = logisticRegr.predict(testData.astype(float))` you would get `NameError: global name 'logisticRegr' is not defined`.

now to solve your issue. initialize/declare your `logisticRegr` model variable after you initialize your `app` variable like this:

```
# Create Flask object to run
app = Flask(__name__)
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()
```

and then remove variable initialization from your `load_model` after `test_y = label_y[700:1000]`

*PS : It's recommended to capitalize your global variables. to easily recognize them in your code.*

Comment: That seems to fix the issue of NameError. However, once I do that, I'm getting a different error: `NotFittedError: This LogisticRegression instance is not fitted yet`. Interestingly, the script with the changes work when it is not placed inside a container.

Comment: One thing that fixed this was putting the whole "load_model" method inside the "predict" method. However, this means that whenever the API is called, the model trains with all the data in the csv file.